# Getting the differences of items in the same index on 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays of equal length containing integers.

How do I get the difference of each index between the 2 arrays using javascript? Please see example below:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
var y = [4, 5, 1];
```

How do I get the absolute difference of `1 - 4`, `2 - 5` and `3 - 1`? Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. If you've never used a loop before, perhaps you should be using a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = x.map((e,i) => e - y[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

> ES6 version

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3];
const y = [4, 5, 1];

const result = x.map((el, index) => el - y[index]);

console.log(result) // [ -3, -3, 2 ]
```

> ES5 version

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3];
var y = [4, 5, 1]; 

var result = x.map(function(el, index) {
  return el - y[index]; 
}); 

console.log(result) // [ -3, -3, 2 ]
```

Comment: you shoud add the ES5 version of your code `var x = [1, 2, 3];
var y = [4, 5, 1];

var result = x.map(function(el, index) {
  return el - y[index];
});

console.log(result) //[ -3, -3, 2 ]`

Comment: Ok, no problem.